# Cannot Mount NTFS devices on Yosemite

Tags: macos, mount, ntfs

I've recently upgrade my iMac to Yosemite. So far, NTFS devices (such as pen dirves or hard drives) were not a problem, but with Yosemite I can't even mount them.

I can see the devices with the Disk Utility app but whenever I try to mount them I always get the same message "Disk could not be mounted" with no further explanations.

I've tried Paragon and Tuxera with no results.
Could this be a USB driver problem?

Comment: You asked _"Could this be a USB driver problem?"_, have you tried mounting a FAT32 formatted USB device?

Comment: Yes, and it worked fine.

Comment: I succeded yesterday: I had to mount it manually from the shell: mount -t ntfs /dev/disk1s1 /Volumes/usb_folder. Still, I have no write permissions.